# Python ElementTree parse xml with NoneType exception

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, nonetype

I meet a problem that is so werid. Here is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# filename: parse_dblp.py
# author: ivanchou

import codecs, os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
paper_tag = ('article','inproceedings','proceedings','book',
             'incollection','phdthesis','mastersthesis','www')

class AllEntities:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return key


print ('----------parse begin----------')

# the parse result store to authors
result = codecs.open('authors','w','utf-8')

parser = ET.XMLParser()
parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
parser.entity = AllEntities()

for event, article in ET.iterparse('dblp_part.xml', events=("start", 

"end"), parser=parser):
    for author in article.findall('author'):
        result.write(author.text + u'|')
    if event == 'end' and article.tag in paper_tag:
        result.write(os.linesep)
    article.clear()
print ('----------parse end----------')
```

The file dblp_part.xml i have create a gist here:
[dblp_part.xml](https://gist.github.com/bigsquirrel/396cc6c88a337505bb38)

It contains the head 2336 line of the dblp.xml, and the last article element it returns me NoneType error, and if i exchange the last two element, it's all ok. So is this a bug of ElementTree?

I am newer of python, search of help.

Comment: dblp_part.xml has some that is not proper xml

Comment: @Leon it's proper xml